# Add arguments in PhantomJs Config : SSL-Protocol

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs, phantomcss

I add PhantomJs to my project as a maven module to test the Projet Status even after modifications to be sure that i didn't domage anything.
When i compile the maven module, i have a problem with with https link in my Project:

```
--- frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.26:grunt (grunt build) @ ess-cms-content ---
[INFO] Running 'grunt phantomcss --no-color' in /path/to/directory

[INFO] Running "phantomcss:desktop" (phantomcss) task
[INFO] [warning] [phantom] Loading resource failed with status=fail:https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.option
[INFO] [PhantomCSS] Screenshot capture failed: No element matching selector found: div.page
```

I have found from my search that i should deactivate ssl. I shouldn't do it using terminal.
How can i add option directly in PhantomJs configuration ?

Comment: How exactly are you currently using PhantomJS/PhantomCSS? In plain PhantomJS it is easy to specify it in the `--config=config.json` file as a commandline option.

Comment: Where should i add command arguments in PhantomJs ?

Comment: As I said, I have no idea how you're using PhantomJS. How are you calling it? How did you install it? You've also tagged the question with CasperJS, but I don't see any connection to PhantomCSS.

Comment: I have install it as an argument in grunt dependency in pom.xml. I have defined tasks to do in phantomcss.js, I have modified the output to see what happen